# How to use Spree's Authentication in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, spree, spree-auth-devise

i am learning rails and creating a web app which also got ecommerce in it
There is a Form which user can fill only if he is logged in, For that i was using Devise, then for e-commerce i installed Spree
Spree got its own login authentication, and there is no authenticate_user! in controllers too,
i removed devise and having a tough time finding how to use Spree's authentication with my Form

here is **UPDATED** Form's controller:
    complaints_controller.rb

```
module Spree
class ComplaintsController < Spree::StoreController
  before_action :require_login

  before_action :set_complaint, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /complaints
  # GET /complaints.json



 def require_login
      redirect_to spree_login_path unless current_spree_user
    end 


      def index
        @complaints = Complaint.all
      end

  # GET /complaints/1
  # GET /complaints/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /complaints/new
  def new
    @complaint = Complaint.new
  end

  # GET /complaints/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /complaints
  # POST /complaints.json
  def create
    @complaint = Complaint.new(complaint_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @complaint.save
        format.html { redirect_to @complaint, notice: 'Complaint was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @complaint }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @complaint.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /complaints/1
  # PATCH/PUT /complaints/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @complaint.update(complaint_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @complaint, notice: 'Complaint was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @complaint }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @complaint.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /complaints/1
  # DELETE /complaints/1.json
  def destroy
    @complaint.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to complaints_url, notice: 'Complaint was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_complaint
      @complaint = Complaint.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def complaint_params
      params.require(:complaint).permit(:id_society, :id_user, :heading, :text, :active, :action, :IsDelete, :flat_number)
    end
end
end
<% end %>
```

index.html.erb

```
  <% if spree_current_user %>
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Complaints</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id society</th>
      <th>Id user</th>
      <th>Heading</th>
      <th>Text</th>
      <th>Active</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>Isdelete</th>
      <th>Flat number</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @complaints.each do |complaint| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= complaint.id_society %></td>
        <td><%= complaint.id_user %></td>
        <td><%= complaint.heading %></td>
        <td><%= complaint.text %></td>
        <td><%= complaint.active %></td>
        <td><%= complaint.action %></td>
        <td><%= complaint.IsDelete %></td>
        <td><%= complaint.flat_number %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', complaint %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_complaint_path(complaint) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', complaint, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Complaint', new_complaint_path %>

<% else %>
<h1> please login</h1>
<% end %>
```

This works, as it verifies user's authentication in View, is there any way to check it in controller? Like if user is logged in it will be sent to action or else redirected to login?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spree uses devise authentication through a extension:

```
https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise
```

For authenticate your actions at controller(your own controllers) level, you need to define your own authentication filter. So you can manage something like this:

```
before_action :require_login

def require_login
  redirect_to login_url unless current_spree_user
end
```

Comment: its still not working and its still going to that action without user logged in @dipak

Comment: could you paste your controller again after adding this filter?

Comment: did you debug the code. like what is returning value for current_spree_user?

Comment: restarted the server and its working now, Thank you @dipak